# How would I toggle an object property between true and false?

Tags: javascript

```js
let myLibrary = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "The Once and Future King",
    author: "White",
    pages: 654,
    read: false,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
    read: false,
  },
];

const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");

function displayBook(book) {
  const addBook = document.createElement("div");
  addBook.className = "book";
  addBook.id = book.id;

  bookContent.appendChild(addBook);

  addBook.innerHTML = `
        <div class="title">
            <p class="bookTitle">
                <span>${book.title}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>
                Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read">
            <label class="switch" data-book="0">
               <input type="checkbox" />
               <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
       </div>
       <div class="delete">
            <button class="delete-btn">DELETE</button>
       </div>`;
}

// Display your original object list
myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
  displayBook(book);
});

// Handle your object creation
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", updateLibrary);

function updateLibrary(event) {
  // Need this so it doesn't refresh page
  event.preventDefault();

  const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  const pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;

  const book = {
    title: title,
    author: author,
    pages: parseInt(pages),
    read: false,
  };

  // Adds object to array
  myLibrary.push(book);

  // Displays new book
  displayBook(book);

  // Reset form
  resetForm();

  // Close form
  document.getElementById("addBookForm").style.display = "none";

  console.log(myLibrary);
}

// Resets the form so user can input another book
function resetForm() {
  document.getElementById("form").reset();
}

// The form is automatically set to hidden. This loads it up for the user
const openForm = function () {
  document.getElementById("addBookForm").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("title").focus();
};

// Sets the form display back to none
const closeForm = () =>
  (document.getElementById("addBookForm").style.display = "none");
```

```css
/* .main {
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #c689c6;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #3b133b;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4649ff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3134fa;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #fffdfa;
  height: auto;
}

.book {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  color: #d9480f;
  width: 280px;
  height: 365px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa94d;
}

.title p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: larger;
}

.title span {
  color: #3c4048;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.body p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

p span {
  color: #3c4048;
}

.read {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #3d8361;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #3d8361;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.delete {
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa94d;
}

.delete-btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e94560;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.delete-btn:hover {
  background-color: #e7082d;
}

.close-btn {
  color: #e7082d;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: #c689c6;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* THE FORM */

.form-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #3b133b;
  animation: openForm 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes openForm {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.form h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: #c689c6;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-container h1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.form-container input[type="text"],
.form-container input[type="number"] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
}

.form-container input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-container input[type="number"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <button class="btn" id="btn" onclick="openForm()">Add a Book</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form" id="addBookForm">
          <form id="form" action="" class="form-container">
            <button type="button" class="close-btn" onclick="closeForm()">
              x
            </button>
            <h1>Add a Book</h1>

            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Title"
              name="title"
              id="title"
              required
            />

            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Author"
              name="author"
              id="author"
              required
            />

            <label for="pages">Pages</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Pages"
              name="pages"
              required
              id="pages"
            />
            <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a form where the user inputs information from a book they are reading and upon hitting submit, the information is sent as its own object inside an array. I also have a forEach method running which loops through the array and displays each object as a div on the web page.

```
let myLibrary = [];

const book = {
  title: title,
  author: author,
  pages: parseInt(pages),
  read: false,
};

myLibrary.push(book)
```

As you can see from the code above, the three properties that the user fills out are the books title, author and page count. There's also a property that is automatically added called the read property and it is automatically set as false.

**The Problem**

My problem is this. I have the following code displayed at the bottom of each div.

```
<div class="read">
    <label class="switch">
       <input type="checkbox" />
       <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

This code is very simple. It's a toggle switch which I found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp).

I want it so when the toggle switch is grayed out, the read status is set to `false`. But when the toggle switch is turned on, the read property is set to `true`. I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to get this done.

**What I've Tried**

I was able to use an onclick to select the toggle switch's parent element, and I tested it using console.log however I am unsure of where to go from there. I attempted to update the `book.read` to `true` using the ternary operator but it was out of scope and resulted in an error.

```
document.querySelector(".main").onclick = (ev) => {
  let el = ev.target.classList.contains("switch")
    ? ev.target.parentElement
    : ev.target.classList.contains("slider")
    ? ev.target
    : false;
  if (el) {
    let toggle = el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    let index = [...toggle.parentElement.children].indexOf(toggle);
    myLibrary[index].read = false ? false : true;
    console.log(myLibrary[index].read);
  }
  console.log(myLibrary);
};
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
function displayBook(book) {
  ...
  <label class="switch" data-book="0">
```

to

```
function displayBook(book,bookIndex) {
  ...
  <label class="switch" data-book="${bookIndex}">
```

and

```
myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
  displayBook(book);
});
```

to

```
myLibrary.forEach((book,i) => {
  displayBook(book,i);
});
```

lastly change

```
// Displays new book
displayBook(book);
```

to

```
// Displays new book
displayBook(book,myLibrary.length-1);
```

Here is the code inclusive a delete function

It would be slightly simpler if we had an associate array on book_id

Note I removed the numeric ID because it is not needed since the index of the array is the same

```js
let myLibrary = [{
    title: "The Once and Future King",
    author: "White",
    pages: 654,
    read: false,
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
    read: false,
  },
];

const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");
const formDiv = document.getElementById("addBookForm");

function displayBook(book, idx) {
  const addBook = document.createElement("div");
  addBook.className = "book";
  addBook.id = `book_${idx}`;

  bookContent.appendChild(addBook);

  addBook.innerHTML = `
        <div class="title">
            <p class="bookTitle">
                <span>${book.title}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>
                Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read">
            <label class="switch" data-book="${idx}">
               <input type="checkbox" />
               <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
       </div>
       <div class="delete">
            <button class="delete-btn">DELETE</button>
       </div>`;
}

// Display your original object list
myLibrary.forEach((book, i) => {
  displayBook(book, i);
});

const deleteBook = (e) => {
  const parent = e.target.closest("div.book");
  const idx = parent.querySelector(".switch").dataset.book;
  parent.remove();
  console.log(idx);
  myLibrary.splice(idx, 1);
  console.log(myLibrary);
  content.querySelectorAll("div.book").forEach((book, i) => { // reset the hard way
      book.id = `book_${i}`;
      book.querySelector("label.switch").dataset.book = i;
  })
};
content.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".delete-btn")) return; // not the delete
  deleteBook(e); // pass the event to the delete
})

// Handle your object creation
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", updateLibrary);

function updateLibrary(event) {
  // Need this so it doesn't refresh page
  event.preventDefault();

  const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  const pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;

  const book = {
    title: title,
    author: author,
    pages: parseInt(pages),
    read: false,
  };

  // Adds object to array
  myLibrary.push(book);

  // Displays new book
  displayBook(book);

  // Reset form
  resetForm();

  // Close form
  formDiv.style.display = "none";

  console.log(myLibrary);
}

// Resets the form so user can input another book
function resetForm() {
  document.getElementById("form").reset();
}

// The form is automatically set to hidden. This loads it up for the user
const openForm = function() {
  formDiv.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("title").focus();
};

// Sets the form display back to none
const closeForm = () => formDiv.style.display = "none";
```

```css
/* .main {
} */

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #c689c6;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #3b133b;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4649ff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3134fa;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #fffdfa;
  height: auto;
}

.book {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  color: #d9480f;
  width: 280px;
  height: 365px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa94d;
}

.title p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: larger;
}

.title span {
  color: #3c4048;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.body p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

p span {
  color: #3c4048;
}

.read {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #3d8361;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #3d8361;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.delete {
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa94d;
}

.delete-btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e94560;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.delete-btn:hover {
  background-color: #e7082d;
}

.close-btn {
  color: #e7082d;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: #c689c6;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* THE FORM */

.form-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #3b133b;
  animation: openForm 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes openForm {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.form h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: #c689c6;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-container h1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.form-container input[type="text"],
.form-container input[type="number"] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
}

.form-container input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-container input[type="number"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <button class="btn" id="btn" onclick="openForm()">Add a Book</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="form" id="addBookForm">
      <form id="form" action="" class="form-container">
        <button type="button" class="close-btn" onclick="closeForm()">
              x
            </button>
        <h1>Add a Book</h1>

        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" id="title" required />

        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Author" name="author" id="author" required />

        <label for="pages">Pages</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Pages" name="pages" required id="pages" />
        <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the unary `+` here: `+el.dataset.book`?

Comment: (If you are attempting to coerce a string nonnegative integer-like value to a Number, doing so is unnecessary because JavaScript arrays are string-indexed.)

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it would work. I've been reading through it trying to fully understand it. However, putting it inside my other code block which is a function that adds an object to the myLibrary array doesn't trigger. I also tried putting it outside the scope and clicking the slider works but I get a ReferenceError.

Comment: @BenAston It was a preventive measure, I was not sure since I have never tested the difference between [1] and ["1"]

Comment: @BenAston This is a sensible thing to do if you are writing TypeScript, I guess. In JavaScript, not that much (it will only save you if your attribute has extra leading zeroes; for anything else, you are just trading a random property for a predictably `"NaN"` property).

Comment: @Amadan This is a JavaScript question.

Comment: @BenAston I know. I did say "if". I meant it may have been from a force of habit, if one is used to writing typed code.

Comment: @mplungjan just added more. hope this makes my problem more clear. thanks for the help.

Comment: @mplungjan okay I just did. Hopefully that wasn't too much. I'll trim it after you check it out.

Comment: @Dagger I think we have a working version now

Comment: @mplungjan Hey! I really appreciate you going through all this trouble to make me a delete button. I'll definitely be using it. However, I was mainly looking to find a way to toggle between the myLibrary[index].read status. I want to have the toggle set it back and forth between false and true. Again I really appreciate all your help so far!!!